# Force to show the billing address form on checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, billing-address

What I want to do is to force user to fill out the billing address on step two at checkout.

In my javascript file I've added a subscription:

```
quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function (billingAddress) {
    billingAddress.isAddressDetailsVisible = function () {
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is that the in the file:

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js`

there is a subscription too:

```
quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function (newAddress) {
```

and in `line 104`:

```
this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
```

And this subsciption is running after my subscription so the value always  will be `true`, and the form not shown.

Is there a method to force this to set `false`? I want to show the form anyway.